# Resetting value of p:inputText in p:inplace when DB constraint validation failed

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have this code:

```
<p:inplace id="staffno" editor="true">
                    <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{staffbean.onSave}" update="staffnoInplace messages" />                    
                    <p:inputText id="staffnoInplace" value="#{staffbean.vieweditStaff.staffno}"/>                                                 
</p:inplace>
```

In staffbean.onSave() I store this through JPA/Hibernate. In the case where its successful, I face no issues. It's stored in the DB.

My problem has to do with the cases where Hibernate throws an exception due to DB constraints. In those cases, I would like to have the inplace to remain in editable state and NOT change the value. Currently, it fails on DB level but I still see the value changed on the UI object to the incorrect value.

Answer (score 2):

You should include a validation method or validator for the `inputText` component so as to reverse the bean value and prevent execution of the `onSave` event when the given ID already exists in the database.

Knowingly attempting to insert a record into a database hoping for database constraints to provide validation is a nebulous data security practice.  I am not saying that database constraints are bad, I am just saying that you should make every attempt to validate and santize your inputs before attempting to insert into the database.

Include a validation method in your managed bean like such:

```
public void validateStaffNoId(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
        throws ValidatorException {
    //Query DB to see if ID exists...
    if (idExists()) {
        //Throw validator exception
    }
}
```

Then in your inputText component simply add the attribute:

```
<p:inputText ... validator="#{staffBean.validateStaffNoId}" ... />
```

Comment: I had hoped to avoid this because this means I have to do an additional DB-query just to verify the existence of an entity. Is there any other way? Can I reverse the bean in some other way? Why is it bad to rely on constraint exceptions?

Comment: @javaMS `is it bad to rely on constraint exceptions?` That is a very good question and still debated to this day.  See here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/76052/constraints-in-a-relational-databases-why-not-remove-them-completely

Comment: @javaMS In the case of JSF, there is the Validation phase where the entire framework will handle applying and rolling back values based on Application Validation.  JSF encourages this model so it is best to do it this way regardless of your feelings on the subject.  Another point is that some databases perform worse by enforcing referential integrity than by fetching a single record.  The performance loss of pre-fetching this record should be minimal if the table is properly indexed.

Comment: I fully buy what you are saying but I still dont like the design with two queries when I can have it solved using one. Your second point is convincing. However, in order to comply with the framework, can I manually fail the validation in my exception handling? I tried using                 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse(); but it only does half the job, i.e. leaves the field in editable mode and provides me with the error message. It does not allow any further action and cancel button doesn't work.

Comment: There is actually another reason for why catching the Exception might be preferable: concurrency. In case of two clients, C1 and C2 trying to write to DB, if I merely rely on application code then it might be that the first query (check query) applied when C1 was trying to write will return "no records found", but C2 writes immediately after that check but before C1 has managed to write to the DB.

Comment: @javaMS If you want to chat about this I created a chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/18167/discussion-between-maple-shaft-and-javams?tab=general  I will be in there for a little while, BalusC can join too if he wishes.

Comment: I went into the chatroom but you weren't there. I think it will be difficult to "match" our timings due to regional timing differences. Would appreciate if you, BalusC or some other guru had any solution proposals for this...

Comment: @javaMS **Concurrency** - This is best addressed by use of Transactions.  You can set up a transaction such that the database will only commit changes when the transaction is complete, and so that other transactions can or cannot see dirty data. You can also lock records. **Validation** If you are in the Validation phase then just throwing a Validator exception will be enough to cancel all posted form values and all JSF events for that request. If it is after validation phase, then you create a FacesMessage with a Severity ERROR attribute and call `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage`

Comment: **Concurrency** can you explain more about the approach you mentioned in the first paragraph with an example? I prefer not to lock records. **Validation** I believe that I have passed the Validation phase. I'm adding a FacesMessage the way you mention and it correctly cancels the workflow. The problem is that it does not allow me to continue, i.e. to change the value of the input and do a new AJAX call / form submit. Any ideas on this?

Comment: @javaMS I could write a book about using Transactions in Hibernate, so instead you should fully read and try to comprehend the [following article that talks about the theory and concepts](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html).  **Validation** I have no clue. Perhaps there is an exception occurring later or a javascript error?  It is too hard to tell without looking at code.

Comment: What part of the code do you want? The java part? I was reading here on stacktrace that when validation fails after an AJAX-call, you can not proceed further except through some complicated work-around. Let me know the code that you would like to see.